# Is there a way to preload Apollo's cache-inmemory with raw data?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

We don't have server currently. We're using Apollo client purely on client side with `apollo-link-state` and `apollo-link-rest`. I want to prevent the loading state of the application as I can have the raw data I would get from the REST endpoint during site load. The closest I could get was using our `customFetch` handler where `IF response exists in cache THEN return new Response() with that data`. The problem is that this will trigger the loading state for a moment. I want to avoid this rerender in the application. I cannot use `writeQuery()` as it would need all the custom types and transformations applied before and the dataset is pretty complex. What I want is to feed my cache at initialization with raw, unprocessed data.